# Not able to find the locator which is inside a component in Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cypress

I am trying to find the dropdown-arrow locator. I have used the cypress cmd - `cy.get('.dropdown-arrow').click()` but it gives element not found error.

Here is my code

```
<widgets-bms-scoreboard>
    <div class="1">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <div class="dropdown-arrow"> </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</widgets-bms-scoreboard>
```

Comment: I've seen a similar thing in Angular that is testable with Cypress.

Comment: Hi @user16695029: yes, the application was built in VueJs. I am not able to figure out why cypress is giving 'element not found' exception.

Comment: I'm interested in the tag `<widgets-bms-scoreboard>` in case it is blocking access to the inner elements (same as an iframe would do, ironically). Specifically, what does the Vue template look like in that component and also is it Vue2 or Vue3 (have to ask that these days).

Comment: It is in vue2. Seems that all the components are in shadow dom

Comment: Add `.shadow()` to your test to open the shadow DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From comments, shadow DOM is present. You can access elements within it either by adding this to cypress.json

```js
{
  "includeShadowDom": true
}
```

or in the test

```js
cy.get('widgets-bms-scoreboard')
  .shadow()
  .find('.dropdown-arrow').click()
```